# Remove specific rows from csv file if matching the elements of a list - python / windows

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with a name and url per row (on the first column).
On the other hand I have a list with names coming from a script.
I would like to remove the rows in the csv file containing the names in the list.
It sounds simple but I tried several options and none works.

The csv format is:

```
John Doe, johndoe.blog.com
Jane Doe, janedoe.blog.com
Jim Foe, jimfoe.blog.com
```

The list:

```
not_ok_name= [John Doe , Jim Foe]
```

The output of the csv file should be:

```
Jane Doe, janedoe.blog.com
```

On the last attempt I tried the following solution :

```
count= 0
while count< len(not_ok_name):
    writer = csv.writer(open('corrected.csv'))
    for row in csv.reader('myfile.csv.csv'):
        if not row[0].startswith(not_ok_name[count]):
            writer.writerow(row)
    writer.close()
```

Since I am still a newbie I look forward for some simple suggestions.
Thanks.

EDIT:
Just in case there could be some formatting issues with the original data, I am pasting the result of:

```
print repr(open("myfile.csv", "rb").read())

John Doe ,johndoe.blog.com\r\nJane Doe , janedoe.blog.com
```

I hope this could help.
Thanks

EDIT 2:
Here's a code that partially does the work. It removes ONE name. Maybe it helps for developing one for the entire list.

```
reader = csv.reader(open("myfile.csv", "rb"), delimiter=',')
with open('corrected.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for line in reader:
        #for item in Names:
        if not any ("Jim Foe" in x for x in line):
            writer.writerow(line)
            print line
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Well, `"Jim Foe"` does not exist in any row. So I would expect all rows to show up in your output

Comment: You are right, @DanielJimenez pointed it out too. How would you go about reformulating the code?

Comment: Well, in my solution, I made a `set` of blacklisted first names, and checked if the first name (found in each row) existed in that blacklist; and wrote the row to the output *only* if the first name was not found in the blacklist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It uses a generator to exclude the names in the `not_ok_name` list.

```
import csv
with open("C:/path/a.csv","rU") as f,open("C:/path/des.csv","wb") as w:
    not_ok_name= ["John Doe" , "Jim Foe"]
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        name = row[0]
        if name not in not_ok_name:
            w.write(row)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. It creates b.csv (I am assuming this is the "destination" file) but does not remove the not_ok_name list.

Comment: What do you mean it does not remove the not_ok_name list. I tested and i got only the jane done line in the b csv. Yes you can name b it whatever you want @Diego

Comment: I tested it several times and the two files are the same. No differences. What do you suggest?

Comment: @Diego It doesn't make sense. When I run it it only write Jane Doe and the her email address How are you running? What happens if you put a print statement for row right after the `w.write(row)'. Also are you names in your `not_ok_name` match the names in the file exactly?

Comment: I tested with print row. It prints "every" line from a.csv. The names are fine. I am not sure what is going on...totally puzzled.

Comment: Check the code again. I change it to to include the universal reading mode and strip the name. @Diego

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75312/discussion-between-daniel-jimenez-and-diego).

Comment: I posted a code that partially does the job (EDIT 2). Maybe it helps understanding what might work entirely. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you look for Jim Foe and not just Jim as in the `not_ok_name` list?

Comment: Because the not_ok_name list is structured with full names which guarantees that if there are two Jims in the original file with two different last names the output removes only the right Jim.

Comment: Well that's the problem, it need to match exactly. You are giving an example but doing something different.

Comment: You are exactly right !! I did not notice it. How would you reformulate the code? Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you for the solution and specially for the patience to check my code!!! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
not_ok_name = ["John", "Jim"]
not_ok_name = set(not_ok_name)  # sets give us O(1) lookup times

with open('myfile.csv') as infile, open('corrected.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for name, url in csv.reader(infile):  # for each row in the input file
        fname = name.split(None, 1)[0]
        if fname in not_ok_name:
            continue  # if the first name is in the list, ignore the row
        writer.writerow([name, url])
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It creates corrected.csv but still with the names to be removed. It adds a blank line between the existing rows. Not sure why.

Comment: Tested several times and it generates an output witho no changes. What do you think might be happening? Both yours and @DanielJimenez codes look fine to me.

Comment: @Diego: I tested (with python 3.4.2) this and get exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I am using python 2.7. Do you think there might be a difference there?

Comment: @Diego: That really shouldn't make that much of a difference.

Comment: I posted a code that partially does the job (EDIT 2). Maybe it helps understanding what might work entirely. Thanks.