# Filter a csv list using multiple items (another list)

Tags: python, list, csv, filter

I am trying to filter a csv file column (e-mail) using multiple e-mails (a list of items).

For example, this is my complete csv file:

```
name,e-mail,status
John,john_mail,1
Mary,mary_mail,2
Louis,louis_mail,2
Frank,frank_mail,2
Bill,bill_mail,1
```

And this is my second list of items (that occur within the first file), as a csv or txt file:

```
mary_mail
louis_mail
frank_mail
```

How could a Python script generate a new csv file containing the info only of those items in the second list?

Intended result:

```
name,e-mail,status
Mary,mary_mail,2
Louis,louis_mail,2
Frank,frank_mail,2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you read in your data with Pandas, you can filter it: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html . Then, you can output the filtered DataFrame as a new CSV

Comment: There are too many guide how to handle csv file in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific rows from csv file if matching the elements of a list - python / windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639128/remove-specific-rows-from-csv-file-if-matching-the-elements-of-a-list-python) (you want the inverse condition, but that should be easy enough to change from the accepted answer there)

Comment: I answered a similar question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75380098/246801). Use a dict to store the emails you want to match against, then check if the "main" list contains any emails in that dict.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to read your emails from the smaller list into a dict.  Then read in the main (input) CSV and only keep rows that have a matching email in the dict.

Your email list would look something like:

```py
emails = {
    "mary_mail":  None,
    "louis_mail": None,
    "frank_mail": None,
}
```

The *keys* in the dict are the emails you care about.  The *values* are None because you're only using the dict for a very fast lookup to see if the email (key) is present.

Then read your input CSV into a list of rows, that would look like this "list of list of strings":

```py
input_rows = [
    ["John",  "john_mail",  "1"],
    ["Mary",  "mary_mail",  "2"],
    ["Louis", "louis_mail", "2"],
    ["Frank", "frank_mail", "2"],
    ["Bill",  "bill_mail" , "1"],
]
```

Your output CSV is determined by a row from input_rows having an email (in the second field, `row[1]`) that is a key in the emails dict:

```py
output_rows = []
for row in input_rows:
    if row[1] in emails:
        output_rows.append(row)

print(output_rows)
# [
#     ["Mary",  "mary_mail",  "2"],
#     ["Louis", "louis_mail", "2"],
#     ["Frank", "frank_mail", "2"],
# ]
```

Also, the header for the input CSV would look like this list of strings:

```py
header = ["name", "e-mail", "status"]
```

To actually read and write CSV files and copy the header, use the csv module:

```py
import csv

# Create dict of emails
emails = {}
with open("emails.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        emails[row[0]] = None

# Read input CSV
with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)  # keep header
    input_rows = list(reader)  # turn "body" of CSV into a list of list of strings

# Filter input, keeping only rows with a match in emails
output_rows = []
for row in input_rows:
    if row[1] in emails:
        output_rows.append(row)

# Write-out filtered rows
with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(output_rows)
```

Take care to only give `writerow()` a list of strings; `writerows()` needs a list of lists (like I showed when I manually defined input_rows, at the beginning).

Starting with emails.csv:

```
mary_mail
louis_mail
frank_mail
```

and input.csv:

```
name,e-mail,status
John,john_mail,1
Mary,mary_mail,2
Louis,louis_mail,2
Frank,frank_mail,2
Bill,bill_mail,1
```

I get output.csv:

```
name,e-mail,status
Mary,mary_mail,2
Louis,louis_mail,2
Frank,frank_mail,2
```